# JS Twin-Bcrypt salt pattern

Tags: javascript, regex, salt, bcrypt

I've been exploring **Twin-Bcrypt** JavaScript library, and found a strange thing. At one moment, I've made my own salt on server side with PHP `base64_encode(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16))` and used it in `TwinBcrypt.hash()` function, which responded that salt is invalid because of the regular pattern mismatch in library. So, the pattern is:

```
var SALT_PATTERN = /^\$2[ay]\$(0[4-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\$[.\/A-Za-z0-9]{21}[.Oeu]/;
```

and it looks fine for my salt, except for one thing - what the hell is this - `[.Oeu]`?

My first question is, why they expect from salt to end with a *dot*, or *O*, or *e*, or *u*? As far as I know `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()` generates secure **CSPRNG**, but because of the pattern JS library does not want to accept it.

Second question - is there any security reason for the salt to end with `/[.Oeu]/` pattern?

I would be very grateful for any help, because there's no much info about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know bcrypt really well, but it appears that Twin-Bcrypt expects the `salt` parameter to include the full type-tag (`2a`/`2y`/`2x`), cost parameter, *and* actual cryptographic salt value. (I believe this is done to match the expectations of other libraries.) The cryptographic salt value is only the final 22 characters of the `salt` parameter string, which represent a 128-bit value.

To actually solve your problem, you'll need to do two things:

1. Prefix your salt with `$2y$10$` so that it has a type-tag and a cost parameter.
2. Map your PHP `base64_encode` result onto bcrypt's nonstandard base64 values. For reference, the values are:

   ```
   Standard: ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/
   bcrypt:   ./ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789
   ```

   If you simply want to make a standard base64 into a brcypt-base64 string, you can replace all `+` with `.`, but that will result in a different value (because standard `+` is a `62` while `.` is a `0`, and all of the other values are offset as well). If you want a brypt string with the same value as the original, you'll need to replace each character with its bcrypt equivalent.

   You may also need to eliminate trailing `=` from the standard string, if any exist.

---

**Extra information: Why must the salt end with `[.Oeu]`?**

A salt in bcrypt is 128 bits. Each base64 character communicates 6 bits of information. That means that 21 base64 characters can evenly communicate 126 bits. The final 2 bits must be encoded in a final 22nd character. Since that character is defined by only 2 bits, it can only have 4 possible values.

When we examine the base64 character pool for brypt, we see:

```
./ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789
```

Counting from zero, we see that those values appear at indicies:

```
. => 0  = 000000
O => 16 = 010000 
e => 32 = 100000
u => 48 = 110000
```

So those final two bits are setting the high-end bits of the final character.

Comment: This should be added to Wiki. Thank you so much!